# Is there a minimum age at which a fruit tree may be chopped down?

Tags: halacha, trees

Is there a minimum age at which a fruit tree [may](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.6.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) be chopped down?

Is it when it gets above the ground? Produces fruit?

Comment: Consider clarifying why you think that there are unique laws governing the destruction of fruit bearing trees.

Comment: see shviit 4, 10.מאימתיי אין קוצצין האילן בשביעית:  בית שמאי אומרים, כל האילן משיוציא; ובית הלל אומרים, החרובין משישלשלו, והגפנים משיגרעו, והזיתים משינצו, ושאר כל האילן משיוציא.  וכל אילן--כיון שבא לעונת המעשרות, מותר לקוצו.  כמה יהא בזית ולא יקוצנו, רובע; רבן שמעון בן גמליאל אומר, הכול לפי הזית.